# Can't pass extra props to this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following React component handles the enter and exit animations of my site's notifications, which it receives through `this.props.children`:

```
class NotificationWrapper extends React.Component {

    constructor( props ) {              
        super( props );                 
        this.state = { timer: setTimeout( this.props.hideNotification, 3000 ) }     
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps( props, state ) {
        if( props.notification.override ) {             
            clearTimeout( state.timer );            
            return {
                timer: setTimeout( props.hideNotification, 3000 )            
            }       
        }       
        return null; 
    }

    handleCloseNotification() {         
        this.props.hideNotification();      
    }

    render() {      
        return(
            <CSSTransition 
                appear
                classNames="v-slide"            
                in={ this.props.in } 
                mountOnEnter
                timeout={ 200 }
                unmountOnExit
                onEntered={ () => { this.state.timer } }
            >
                { this.props.children }             
            </CSSTransition>
        );  
    }

}

function mapStateToProps( { notification } ) {  return { notification } }

export default connect( mapStateToProps, { hideNotification } )( NotificationWrapper );
```

It generally works fine, but I would like to pass the `hideNotification` prop to `this.props.children` so that, besides being hidden automatically after three seconds, the notification can also be hidden at the click of a 'close' button which is included in the children components.

I've read about `React.cloneElement()` and tried replacing my `this.props.children` with the following:

```
{
    React.cloneElement( this.props.children, {
        handleHideNotification: this.props.hideNotification
    })
}
```

but when I test it, as soon as the notification is mounted to the DOM React throws this error:

> Invalid value for prop `handlehidenotification` on  tag. Either
>   remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep
>   it in the DOM

I can't understand what the problem is...

Comment: Do you want to pass `handleHideNotification` to each and every element that you write a children. This may not be correct since elements like div don't have such props defined on them

Comment: pass handlehidenotification as a prop to NotificationWrapper?

Comment: As i can see `hideNotification` is also available in props and `children` are also available in props. Why not pass `hideNotification` as a prop to each `children` itself where they are defined?

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay Do you mean I should pass it as a custom prop of CSSTransition? 'Cause I have tried that but it doesn't seem possible to pass custom attributes to CSSTransition.

Comment: @HridayModi Yes, that's the temporary fix I'm using, but I would like to find a way to do it all in the `NotificationWrapper` component.

Answer (score 0):

As `props.chidren`is like a list of components, you must iterate over it:

```
{React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, { handleHideNotification: 'your prop here' });
 })}
```

Comment: I had tried this, but I get this error: `Invalid prop 'children' supplied to CSSTransition`

Comment: Sorry @grazianodev. I just fixed the answer. You should use `this.props.children` instead.

Comment: I actually saw the error already and tried with `this.props.children`, but I still get the same error about CSSTransition.

Comment: Have you tried to render `this.props.children` without wrapping it around `<CSSTransition>` to see if that works out?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve your problem is to include a close button with a `onClick` event which fires a method which will call `props.hideNotification`. You will have to add the button just before you inject `props.children`.

```html
import React, { Fragment } from 'React';

class NotificationWrapper extends React.Component {

    constructor( props ) {              
        super( props );                 
        this.state = { timer: setTimeout( this.props.hideNotification, 3000 ) }     
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps( props, state ) {
        if( props.notification.override ) {             
            clearTimeout( state.timer );            
            return {
                timer: setTimeout( props.hideNotification, 3000 )            
            }       
        }       
        return null; 
    }
    

    handleCloseNotification() {         
        this.props.hideNotification();      
    }

    render() {      
        return(
            <CSSTransition 
                appear
                classNames="v-slide"            
                in={ this.props.in } 
                mountOnEnter
                timeout={ 200 }
                unmountOnExit
                onEntered={ () => { this.state.timer } }
            >
                <Fragment>
                  <button onClick="handleCloseNotification">Close</button>
                  { this.props.children }
                </Fragment>
                           
            </CSSTransition>
        );  
    }

}
```